# New Futures to implement in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Can any one tell me what are the new futures came in asp.net mvc2..

I am looking for View Codding new futures? Controller coding and Seurity?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is Scott Guthrie's Blog with information

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/11/asp-net-mvc-2-released.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[Whats new in asp.net mvc2](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc)